# Collecting study notes on a single A4 sheet

Tags: pdf, note-taking

I read a lot of online docs/PDFs and I'm looking for a software that can help collate info on to an A4 size sheet.

1. I need to cut and paste images and scale/crop/move them about on the A4.
2. I'd like to paste text and move that block of text about and change the font and color; also i'd like to limit the text to a box rather than let it flow.
3. Something that will let me write stuff down and do handwriting analysis and convert that to computer-text (i got bad handwriting).
4. Decorations like underline, recatangle would also be nice.

Currently I use **pdfxchange** viewer which is pretty good for marking up PDFs and I just open up little arrow boxes and cut and paste stuff into the box (annotated doc basically).

Unfortunately, I can't paste images in Wine Linux. Also, it's not concise enough for study notes.

[image: PDFXchange]

Ideally I'd like to use pdfxchange for reading PDF and use something specific for study notes.

I've tried Microsoft **OneNote** but that just gives you a gigantic work sheet of infinite size - which was annoying - no one IRL notes down an infinite paper - they use A4.

So could someone suggest something? Linux isn't essential, I can switch but not to a Mac - too expensive.

**I want something with the flexibility, messiness of handwritten notes - I don't want it line-by-line like a word processor. I want all my related info squeezed into a tiny space, in small print with boxes, arrows, underlines** - kind of like this:

[image: Photo of handwritten notes]

Comment: Why don't you try Google documents which almost does solve the problems you have.

Comment: i've updated my Q to show what i'm using currently - the trouble is all that highlighted text needs to be reduced to simpler, briefer writing vs typing. Google docs looks to be like MS Word.

Comment: something like gimp - an A4 canvas, but lighter and designed for note-making.